# I cannot find anything in LibreOffice help

Tags: 11.10, libreoffice, find

I have packages libreoffice-help-en-gb and libreoffice-help-en-us installed.

LibreOffice 3.4.4 
OOO340m1 (Build:402)

pre-installed on Ubuntu Oneiric

Here is the screen shot.

Error message: [No topics found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raikF.png)

I think it related to JRE because I run a live cd ubuntu and found that it showed a message saying that "this feature requires Java Runtime Environment", but I have JRE 6 installed on my current distribution (not the live cd version) , or maybe it needs JRE 7?

Comment: +1 I get the same thing. It's as if there is no search being performed. All the help files are there and browsable. Try downloading the help files as a PDF and searching in evince as a workaround for now. http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of LibreOffice and from where you sourced it.

Comment: Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot has ended its support since May 9, 2013 and is now obsolete; this might be the issue and LibreOffice need updated packages from repositories that are no more available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "Index" tab.

On the other hand, I cannot find anything as well. Maybe you should file it as a bug upstream: http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/BugReport

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem (12.04)

Used the Software Centere to install: `libreoffice-java-common`

That fixed it for me.